# How to return specific column from database results?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a column named "id" in MySQL
I have to show the username of that id
how to show the "username" column of that id in PHP?

it is database code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '123456', 'profile');
if (!$conn) {
echo mysqli_connect_errno($conn);
echo mysqli_connect_error($conn);
}
```

and it is display code :

```
$get_data = "SELECT * FROM info";
$get_data_query = mysqli_query($conn, $get_data);
$array_data = $get_data_query->fetch_assoc();

$name = $array_data['name'];
```

Comment: Please show us your code. There are several ways to do a SQL request in PHP.

Comment: Welcome. You need to do the [appropriate amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_, post your attempt, explain where you're stuck, the expected result and what currently happens. We're here to help you with concrete issues with your current code, not to write it all for you (which a proper answer here would require us to). There are many many PHP & MySQL tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database query needs to have a 'where' in it if you are searching for a specific ID.

$get_data = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = '1'"; or what ever the id you are looking for. (bear in mind you need to use prepared statements if not hardcoding the query)

In all cases, $array_data will be an array of data (even if it has only one result), so you need to either loop over it to return the values of the columns for each item that is returned.

```
foreach ($array_data as row){
 echo $row['name']
}
```

or return the first item from the results

```
echo current($array_data)['name'];
```